# Como controlar las respuestas de las peticiones http con angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, http

Quisiera saber como manejar excepciones en angularjs. Que artefactos puedo usar o como implementar el manejo de errores.

Tengo el siguiente código:

Este es un ejemplo de mi JSON. Ahora lo que quisiera validar es si la lista "listadoProductos" existe o viene vacío.

```
[{
    "estado":false,
    "id":1,
    "direccion":"Calle José Galvez 1575 Dpto 201 Lince",
    "tipodeFactura":"Facturación",
    "asociado":"998882591",
    "listadoProductos": [{
            "idProducto":"0001",
            "nombreProducto": "Cajita Feliz"
        }
    ],
    "fault":[{
        "errorFun":[{
            "idError":"01",
            "mensaje":"errorfunc"
        }],
        "errorTec":[{
            "idError":"01",
            "mensaje":"errorTec"
        }]
    }]  
}]
```

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente llamado `$http` desde mi service:

```
appServices.service('productoServicio', ['$http', function($http) {

    var UrlProductosServicios = 'http://172.19.74.235:8909/ProductoServiciosResulFull/service/obtenerServicios/p';

    this.getListProductos = function () {
        return $http.get(UrlProductosServicios);
    };
```

El campo `"fault"` del Json debe traer los errores de codificación, funcionalidad, timeout o disponibilidad del servidor. Cómo puedo implementar el manejo de estos errores?
Por favor agradecería su ayuda si me pueden brindar alguna idea de como manejar esto?

Les adjunto tambien como consumo el método getListProductos de mi service en mi controller

```
   productoServicio.getListProductos().then(function (response) {
            $scope.ListProducto  = response.data;
            $scope.estadoConsumer = true;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
            $scope.estado = false;     
        });
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: En la pregunta dices que quieres manejar el error pero no dices como. Que es lo que quieres hacer en caso de error?

Comment: Quisiera mostrar un mensaje, pintarlo en consola .etc gracias

Comment: Este formato del JSON aplica para toda tu aplicación? O sea que cualquier llamada ajax que hagas será un JSON con una propiedad `'fault'` o sólo para esta llamada en particular?

Comment: Si, cualquier llamada ajax que haga traera esa propiedad "fault". que internamente siempre va a tener esas 2 propiedades ("errorFun","errorTec").

Answer (score 3):

Lo que quieres se puede lograr con un [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) para el response

La sintáxis es simple, crea un factory que devuelva un objeto donde las llaves son funciones para manipular cada parte de la petición

```
.factory('myInterceptor', function($q) {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
          // esto se ejecutará antes de que se envíe cada petición
          // puedes modificar la configuración de todas las peticiones
          return config;
      },
      'requestError': function(rejection) {
          // esto se ejecutará cuando la petición tenga errores al enviar
          return $q.reject(rejection);
      },
      'response': function(response) {
          // esto se ejecutará cada vez que una petición retorne satisfactoriamente
          return response
      },
      'responseError': function(rejection) {
          // esto se ejecutará cada vez que una petición retorne con errores      
          return $q.reject(rejection);
      },
    }
  })
```

Cada una de las llaves son opcionales. Luego solo lo agregas usando `$httpConfig` en un `config block` o `$http` en un `run block`.

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
})
```

Sólo te faltaría examinar la propiedad `fault` del objeto que llega.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngMockE2E'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($http) {
    $http.get('/foo');
  })
  .factory('errorInterceptor', function() {
    return {
      'response': function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.fault);
      }
    }
  })
  .config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
  })
  .run(function($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/foo').respond([{
      "estado": false,
      "id": 1,
      "direccion": "Calle José Galvez 1575 Dpto 201 Lince",
      "tipodeFactura": "Facturación",
      "asociado": "998882591",
      "listadoProductos": [{
        "idProducto": "0001",
        "nombreProducto": "Cajita Feliz"
      }],
      "fault": [{
        "errorFun": [{
          "idError": "01",
          "mensaje": "errorfunc"
        }],
        "errorTec": [{
          "idError": "01",
          "mensaje": "errorTec"
        }]
      }]

    }]);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
```